# Do not combine Magento Shopping Cart Price Rules

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I have a "free shipping" Magento shopping cart price rule that is active if the price is over $100.00.

I have other coupons on the site, I want to make the free shopping valid only if no other coupon is used.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be acomplished by given the non-shipping coupons a higher priority number under the "rule information" tab and selecting "Stop Further Rule processing" to "Yes" under actions tab.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it from System->Configuration->Sales->Shipping Method..
There you will find "Free Shipping" and under that you can set free shipping amount by setting "Minimum Order Amount"..
I think this thing will helpful..

Comment: Yes but that does not allow you set whether or not it can be combined with other offers.